# Segfault iterating over a QList

Tags: qt

I've created two classes - one called circle:

```
class circle
{
public:
    circle();
    QString name ;
    int id ;
};
```

and another class that use this class:

```
class soso
{
public:
    soso();
    QList<circle*> lis;
    void go();
};
```

In the constructor of soso I add two circles:

```
soso::soso()
{
    circle* c1 = new circle();
    circle* c2= new circle();
    c1->id=1;
    c1->name="yamen";
    c2->id=2;
    c2->name="hasan";
    lis.append(c1);
    lis.append(c2);
}
```

and in the main window i've called go method which is included here

```
void soso::go()
{

  QFile file("database.txt");
  if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    throw " cannot open file ! ";
  QDataStream out(&file);
  int i=0;
  QList<circle*>::iterator it1 =lis.begin();

  for(i=0;it1!=lis.end();it1++);
  {
    out<<(*it1)->id;    //   segmentation error here
    out<<(*it1)->name;
  }
}
```

But I am getting a segmentation error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try running the app in the debugger?

Answer (score 5):

You have a semicolon after your for loop! Those are really hard to notice.

```
for(i=0;it1!=lis.end();it1++);
```

This works. Just changed it to look more like standard use of iterators:

```
  QList<circle*>::iterator it1;

  for(it1 = lis.begin();it1!=lis.end();it1++)
  {
    out<<(*it1)->id;
    out<<(*it1)->name;
  }
```

Comment: Indeed, good catch, and it's interesting that the code still compiles.